# How to define a list of (parametric) functions (with local())

Tags: r

My goal is to define a list of functions depending on (different) parameters. As
an example, consider a list of power functions with the ith list element being
the ith power function x^i. Here is what I tried:

```
## Version 1: How one would think it works
f <- lapply(1:2, function(i) function(x) x^i))
c(f[[1]](3), f[[2]](3)) # => 9, 9 => wrong

## Version 2: I found out that the following works, but this is not very intuitive code (IMHO)
f <- lapply(1:2, function(i) local({ tmp <- i; function(x) x^tmp }))
c(f[[1]](3), f[[2]](3)) # => 3^1=3, 3^2=9

## Version 3: Interestingly, this works (but why?):
f <- lapply(1:2, function(i) local({ tmp <- i; function(x) x^i }))
c(f[[1]](3), f[[2]](3)) # => 3^1=3, 3^2=9
```

I have two questions:

1) Why does version 3 work (although tmp is not really
used)?

2) What's the most intuitive approach to problems of this type (I assume s.th. with local() but maybe more convenient than Version 2/3)

Comment: @James: It is (and even a similar example :-) ). Very good answer.

Comment: @Avinash: This does *not* work for me (current R-devel)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't I tested it wrong. I think instead of deleting the comment I should have added an edit. I deleted it, hoping you did not see it